# How to make a "generic" C# repository accept a context in its constructor

Tags: c#

I'm going through a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) on how to create a generic MVC repository with Entity Framework. I was able to make the specific name changes so it would work with the system I have in place. From a separate tutorial, I learned how to create an interface and rewrote the generic repository class to implement the interface.

The test worked great. However, I notice that while the repository class is a "generic" class, the class appears to be tied down to one specific database context `SkillJournalContext`. Is there a way that I can replace `SkillJournalContext` with a generic so that I can use the same repository with any other database contexts in my project? (I have two other contexts in the project, each context pointing to separate databases).

I would like to do this so that I do not retype identical code for my other two database contexts. I searched the web using variations of "MVC repository" and "database context parameter" and was led to the same tutorials I used.

Is a repository required to be tied to one specific database context, or can be be made generic as I hope to do?

```
public class GenericRepositorySkill<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
                 where TEntity : class
{
    internal SkillJournalContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepositorySkill(SkillJournalContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // .... and so on
}
```

Comment: What about using the base class `DbContext`? ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx))

Comment: Good idea. Changing `SkillJournalContext` to `DbContext` (along with some required code as a consequence of that) did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from @Mati Cicero, I replaced `SkillJournalContext` with `DbContext`. This did the trick.

I changed the `internal` to a `DbContext` type and changed the parameter to a `DbContext` type. No compilation errors and the browser test worked as intended.

Now that this is not tied to a specific database context, I was able to rename the repository class and constructor accordingly.

```
    internal DbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext _context)
    {
        this.context = _context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```